# Unique numbers generated by subset sum from 1...n

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

Does sum of subset of sequence of positive natural numbers starting from (1...n) generate all unique numbers less than n * (n+1)/2?

eg.
sum(1,2,3) = 6
sub-set sum:

> `1, 2, 3, 1+3 = 4, 2+3 = 5, 1+2+3 = 6`

Is there a theorem that validates the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple proof by induction.

Take each subset of the integers from `1` to `N` consisting of all those values except for some `k` where `k` is in the range `1` to `N` (excluding `N`). The sum of each of these subsets are the consecutive integers `SUM(1..N)-k` which are all the integers between `SUM(1..N-1) + 1` and `SUM(1..N) - 1`. That's the induction step. The rest of the proof is trivial.